# why the main function can't pass the correct argument to the pthread_creat function

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the philosopher problem by limitating the number of the philosophers who are eating at 4. And in the main function, I code like this to create the threads.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tidp[i], NULL, creatPhilosopher, (void *)&i);
    }
```

but here are the output

```
philosopher 0 is thinking...
philosopher 0 is thinking...
philosopher 0 is thinking...
philosopher 0 is thinking...
philosopher 0 is thinking...
philosopher 0 is eating...
philosopher 0 is eating...
philosopher 0 is eating...
philosopher 0 is eating...
philosopher 0 is eating...
```

while, I tried another way like this

```
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int* temp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *temp = i;
        pthread_create(&tidp[i], NULL, creatPhilosopher, (void *)temp);
    }
```

and the output is correct.

```
philosopher 4 is thinking...
philosopher 3 is thinking...
philosopher 2 is thinking...
philosopher 1 is thinking...
philosopher 0 is thinking...
philosopher 4 is eating...
philosopher 3 is eating...
philosopher 2 is eating...
philosopher 1 is eating...
philosopher 0 is eating...
philosopher 4 is thinking...
philosopher 3 is thinking...
philosopher 2 is thinking...
philosopher 1 is thinking...
```

So, what's the difference between the two ways?

Comment: If you use C++ you should use `std::thread` and `new` instead of `ptghread_create` and `malloc`, And in that case you would not need new/malloc as you can pass by value to `std::thread`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you have only one single memory location that is passed to all the different threads: the address of variable `i`. So all threads will read their number from the *same* place. What they read from there depends on when they read that value. It seems a bit odd that all read 0, but in any case, this is not what you want.

In the second case you give each thread a *different* memory location. So each thread reads from a different location and thus a different number.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you pass a pointer/reference/handle to the same variable, for every thread. One variable holds one value. You're also not synchronising accesses to that variable (not to mention it could be destroyed before every thread is done trying to read from it), so really all bets are off.

In the second example, each thread gets a copy of `i` with the correct value, and since the variables are independent objects you also have thread-safety.

You should always be thinking about object lifetime, ownership and access patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is undefined behavior.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     pthread_create(&tidp[i], NULL, creatPhilosopher, (void *)&i);
}
```

Neither the C++ standard, nor POSIX, whose thread API you are using, gives you any guarantee, whatsoever, that `createPhilosopher` will start executing and read the value of the pointer that gets passed to it before the `for` loop's iteration finishes, so that the new thread reads the current value of `i`. There is no guarantee that `createPhilosopher` actually starts executing before `pthread_create` returns in the main execution thread. It may, or may not. It depends on the phase the moon, and the tides.

And by the time the execution threads start executing, it's likely that the entire `for` loop has finished, and is just a distant memory. It called `pthread_create` some number of times (but they execution threads have not yet started executing), and, in fact, the `i` variable is now been destroyed and no longer exists (wherever it was declared), and its memory is now occupied by some other randomly-chosen value, or it's garbage, so by the time the new execution threads read the pointer that they receive as a parameter, it is pointing to garbage.

In the other case you're allocating a single `int` value in dynamic scope that still exists when the execution threads actually start executing, so they read the value. Nothing `free`s them, so the pointer are still value. And you leaked memory, but that's another story.

Comment: Never been too fond of the _"it is pointing to garbage"_ nomenclature; that suggests it's a valid pointer that just happens to have arbitrary data at the other end. That's not true, because C++ is an abstraction. It's an invalid/dangling pointer that effectively _doesn't point to anywhere or anything at all_.

Comment: `i` is not declared in the loop, and from code snippet we do not know if it is destroyed before threads finished